# NSX-T provider for Terraform not locating tier0 router

Tags: terraform

I'm encountering a strange issue with Terraform's NSX-T provider. I'm referencing my Tier-0 router as a datasource, but I cannot use it in my resources.

Tier-0 Router data source:

```
data "nsxt_logical_tier0_router" "tier0_router" {
  id = "c8a3e87c-ec49-4586-ad2e-ada799e0fd34"
}
```

Logical router resource:

```
# Router downlink
resource "nsxt_logical_router_downlink_port" "downlink_port" {
  description                   = "DP1 provisioned by Terraform"
  display_name                  = "vendor_bastion"
  logical_router_id             = nsxt_logical_tier0_router.tier0_router.id
  linked_logical_switch_port_id = nsxt_logical_port.logical_port1.id
  ip_address                    = "10.30.3.252/24"
}
```

It errors on the "nsxt_logical_tier0_router.tier0_router.id" line saying:

```
Error: Reference to undeclared resource
on tf-nsxt.tf line 46, in resource "nsxt_logical_router_downlink_port" "downlink_port":
46:   logical_router_id             = nsxt_logical_tier0_router.tier0_router.id
A managed resource "nsxt_logical_tier0_router" "tier0_router" has not been
declared in the root module.
```

The strange part is that if I put that ID on line 46 it works fine. Anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out and forgot to come back and post. The solution is that when you're referencing data, you need to add "data." in front of reference. So the correct way to reference the router is below:

```
# Router downlink
resource "nsxt_logical_router_downlink_port" "downlink_port" {
  description                   = "DP1 provisioned by Terraform"
  display_name                  = "vendor_bastion"
  logical_router_id             = data.nsxt_logical_tier0_router.tier0_router.id
  linked_logical_switch_port_id = nsxt_logical_port.logical_port1.id
  ip_address                    = "10.30.3.252/24"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the provider reference (https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/nsxt/r/logical_router_downlink_port.html):

> logical_router_downlink_port: This resource provides a means to define a downlink port on a logical router to connect a logical tier1 router to a logical switch. The result of this is to provide a default gateway to virtual machines running on the logical switch.

If you want co connect tier0 with tier1 you should use `nsxt_logical_router_link_port_on_tier0` on this page: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/nsxt/r/logical_router_link_port_on_tier0.html